# Visual Studio 2012 - Table Designer Menu missing

Tags: database-design, visual-studio-2012

Accoding to msdn I get the 'Table Designer Menu' when opening the Table Designer:

From MSDN:
1)Right-click the table under the Tables node of your connection in Server Explorer.
2)From the drop-down menu, click Open Table Definition.
3)The Table Designer menu will be added to the main menu and the table will open in the designer panes.

However, I do not get the menu. I get the Table Designer and can create and edit tables, but the menu is not there.
Any ideas what's going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Table Designer does not exist in all versions of Visual Studio.
Check on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8czxd086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).